# Why isn't my promise resolving and topicFilter updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, redux

These are methods in my `createPost` screen.

Each `post` can have up to 3 `topics` associated with it: `selectedTopics`

The main feed has an ability to filter the posts by topics: `topicFilter`

When a user creates a post, I want to check to see if any of the `selectedTopics` is in one of the users `interests`. If it is, then `topicFilter` will be set to `My Top Interests`.

Both the `hot` and `new` feed will refresh with this `topicFilter` and then the app will navigate from the `createPost` screen to the `feed` screen.

However, if none of the `selectedTopics` for the post are in the users' `interests`, then `topicFilter` will be set to the first of the topics in `selectedTopics`. And as with the other case, the feeds will refreshed and the app will navigate to the `feed` screen.

This is not working.

Here is the `createPost` method:

```
createPost() {
    const { text, image, mongoId, selectedTopics, topicCount } = this.props;
    const postToUniOnly = this.state.postToUniOnly;
    if (topicCount > 0) {
      if (image) {
        this.props.createPostWithImage(text, image, postToUniOnly, mongoId, selectedTopics);
      } else {
        this.props.createPostNoImage(text, postToUniOnly, mongoId, selectedTopics);
      }
      const myInterestsPostTopicMatch = this.seeIfAnyPostTopicsInMyInterests();

      if (myInterestsPostTopicMatch)
        this.ChangeTopicFilterToMyInterestsAndNavigate()
          .then(() => this.refreshFeed())
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

      else
        this.ChangeTopicFilterToOtherAndNavigate()
          .then(() => this.refreshFeed())
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
```

This checks to see if any of the `selectedTopics` are in the users' `interests`:

```
  seeIfAnyPostTopicsInMyInterests() {
    const { selectedTopics, interests } = this.props;

    return interests.some((interest) => selectedTopics.indexOf(interest) >= 0);
  }
```

These are the promises for each:

```
 ChangeTopicFilterToMyInterestsAndNavigate() {
    const { topicFilter } = this.props;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.toggleTopicFilter('My Top Interests');
      this.props.navigator.pop(2);

      if (topicFilter === 'My Top Interests') resolve();
      else reject('could not switch to my interests');
    });
  }

  ChangeTopicFilterToOtherAndNavigate() {
    const { selectedTopics, topicFilter } = this.props;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.toggleTopicFilter(selectedTopics[0]);
      this.props.navigator.pop(2);

      if (topicFilter === selectedTopics[0]) resolve();
      else reject('could not switch to other topicFilter');
    });
  }
```

And here is the `refreshFeed`:

```
  refreshFeed() {
    const { uniOnly, topicFilter } = this.props;
    this.props.fetchPostsByHottest(topicFilter, uniOnly);
    this.props.fetchPostsByNewest(topicFilter, uniOnly);
  }
```

Right now the `topicFilter` does get changed appropriately. But it is not doing so before it can refresh the feed.

It's also navigating to the feed. But both promises are being rejected, log the errors, and do not `refresh` the feed.

What can I do to fix this? Thank you

Comment: What does `this.props.navigator.pop(2);` trigger? What are the exact values of topicFilter once the promise gets rejected?

Comment: this navigates screens in react native. It's working just fine.

topicFilter when logged in the promise, is the same as it was before making the post.

If I then check the filter, I can see that it WAS changed to what it needs to be. Just not quick enough. So the promise fails and the feed isn't refreshed.

Comment: It is possible that the call to `this.props.navigator.pop(2);` should be just before `this.refreshFeed()` in the promise resoolution callback? If it navigates back to a state where topicFilter wasn't updated yet, your promises obv reject.

Comment: For example. if the `topicFilter` is `My Top Interests` before making the post and the user then makes a post with `selectedTopics` containing `Politics` but their `interests` doesn't have `Politics` in their interests...

Then `topicFilter` WILL be changed to `Politics`. But not before it fails the promise.

Comment: nah, that doesn't work, it'll just fail to navigate

Comment: I'm sorry, don't think I'll be able to figure this one out like on friday, since I'm having alot of difficulty understanding what is and what isn't async. My advice would be, don't overuse promises, keep all the sync stuff synced inside 1 'then' clause and return the next async operation from inside it, becuase the workflow you explain above, sounds completely sync to me until the reload happens. Also, your changeFilterAndNav functions are so similar, it isn't worth having two different ones.